# Zen coding img src from a list

Tags: html, emmet

I'm trying to create a large list of `img` tags from a list of filenames using zen coding to fill the `src` attribute with my list of filenames.

Here's what I have and what I want to do with it:

```
filenameA.jpg
someotherone.jpg
anotherimage.jpg
sample.jpg
```

Zen coding results:

```
<img src="images/filenameA.jpg" />
<img src="images/someotherone.jpg" />
<img src="images/anotherimage.jpg" />
<img src="images/sample.jpg" />
```

I've tried wrapping the list with abbreviation: `img[src=]` 
but I don't know the proper way to do it.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this abbreviation (works in Zen Coding v0.7):

`img[src=images/$#]*`